# Failure in passing an authors option to svn2git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm in the process of migrating from svn to git (on a local repo) where I'm trying to convert all our svn authors to git format by creating a text file under `~/.svn2git/authors.txt`,  for example:

```
jcoglan = James Coglan <jcoglan@never-you-mind.com>
stnick = Santa Claus <nicholas@lapland.com>
```

Then pass an authors option to `svn2git` pointing to that file:

```
$ svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo --trunk trunk --authors ~/.svn2git/authors.txt
```

I'm getting below error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/developer/mygitrepo/.git/
Author: system not defined in /home/developer/mygitrepo/.svn2git/authors.txt file
command failed:
git svn fetch
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that it's found an SVN commit that uses an id `system` and you haven't provided a mapping for that in your authors file. As a result, it doesn't know how to translate SVN's user `system` into a Git name/e-mail address, and so it can't create the commit for you.

You can fix this by adding another line in your authors file:

```
system = System <system@system.com>
```

(or whatever you want to use)